# How to call stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getID(IN username VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE username = username;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is my stored procedure. I called it by using:

```
$sp=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");
$id=$sp->multi_query("CALL getID()");

echo $id;
```

But its not showing the ID. There are no error but still, not retrieving the ID.

Comment: On first glance this seems correct to me. I've found stored procedures pretty hard to debug though. Does your proc work if you call it from your mysql client?

Comment: I suggest you all start reading the documentation of the `multi_query()` call... It returns a _boolean_. Which makes sense. You have to fetch the result afterwards as always when running a query against a database. See the examples in the documentation. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: well I tried with mysql_query as well as mysqli_query. They are showing errors. I saw this multi_query suggested by someone on some other thread

Comment: Read [*this article in PHP site*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)

Comment: Is there any problem coz I have just giving input to the procedure, but there's no output source or variable??

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sp=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");
 $id=$sp->query("CALL getID()");
 while($row = $id->fetch_object())
 {
 debug($row);
 }
```

Comment: I want the return value in a variable "$id" so I can use it futher!

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\slots.php on line 16

Comment: which is undefined variable

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\slots.php on line 15

Comment: $mysqli undefined variable